# Unity Android Game crash android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine, crash, google-play

I have a Android game in Google Play store built with Unity 2018.4.2f1 with IL2CPP instead of Mono.
The used runtime version .Net 3.5, I target ARMv7 and ARM64 and build it as Google App Bundle (*.aab).
Since last update my game crash rate is increasing everyday and 90% of said crashes are related to `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException` with all reporting devices using Android 9.

I am unable to find which part of my game generating this crash. I am using Unity, Vungle, Startapp, Adcolony, leadbolt ads in my game. Does any of these has something to do with this crash?

Google Crash Report:
[image: Google Crash Report]

Crash detail:
[image: Crash Detail]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is generally you're putting too much data into an Intent.  There's a limit (I think its 2 MB but that may be dated) above which you get that error when you send it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am very less familiar of native Android things. As Unity is a Game Engine so i don't know what underlying structure they follow. As far as i know Unity Game runs on single alone activity. And when ads are shown that activity goes into pause state. I don't know whether Ad networks like Admob use their own activity to display ads or not?